# Correct way of using useState hook on radio buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I followed the ReactJS documentation regarding the useState hook but I cannot get it to work with radio buttons. It doesn't select any radio button at all.
By the way I am using react-semantic ui for the component.

The radio buttons should select the gender assigned to the state. I've tried to `console.log` the `gender` variable and it changes but does not reflect on the ui.

Here's my code for your reference.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ListCreateNew = () => {
  const [gender, setGender] = useState('Male');
  return (
      <Form.Group inline>
        <label>Gender</label>
        <Form.Field control={Radio} label="Male" checked={gender === 'Male'} value="Male" onClick={() => setGender('Male')} />
        <Form.Field control={Radio} label="Female" checked={gender === 'Female'} value="Female" onClick={() => setGender('Female')} />
      </Form.Group>
  );
}
```

EDIT: 
I apologize everyone. I've missed the anonymous function on the onClick attrib.

Comment: Your code is working https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-galois-nb4e5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use annonymous function to update the state,

```
<Form.Field control={Radio} label="Male" checked={gender === 'Male'} value="Male" onClick={() => setGender('Male')} />
<Form.Field control={Radio} label="Female" checked={gender === 'Female'} value="Female" onClick={() => setGender('Female')} />
```

---

**Update**

For the radio button, you have [`Form.Radio`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#types-form)

```
<Form.Group inline>
    <label>Gender</label>
    <Form.Radio label="Male" checked={gender === 'Male'} value="Male" onClick={() => setGender('Male')} />
    <Form.Radio label="Female" checked={gender === 'Female'} value="Female" onClick={() => setGender('Female')} />
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: Hi, I added an edit regarding the anonymous function. I actually have that already on my code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are setting it wrong here `checked={() => gender === 'Female'}` it should be ``checked={gender === 'Female'}. Your annonymous function is only on `onClick` jandler.

Comment: Hi, sorry, getting too much typo error. Updated it again.

Comment: @alvirbismonte, check the updated answer, you are referring to the wrong element type for your radio.

Comment: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-field-control

Answer (score 3):

```
const [radio,setRadio] = useState('false')

<Form>

<Form.Check inline label="Response A" type="radio" id="radioA" value="radioA" checked={radio === "radioA"} onChange={(e)=>{setRadio(e.target.value)}}/>

<Form.Check inline label="Response B" type="radio" id="radioB" value="radioB" checked={radio === "radioB"} onChange={(e)=>{setRadio(e.target.value)}}/>
                                
<Form.Check inline label="Response C" type="radio" id="radioC" value="radioC" checked={radio === "radioC"} onChange={(e)=>{setRadio(e.target.value)}}/>
                                
<Form.Check inline label="Response D" type="radio" id="radioD" value="radioD" checked={radio === "radioD"} onChange={(e)=>{setRadio(e.target.value)}}/>
                            
</Form>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a bit of explanation/comments on why/how your code works!

Answer (score 0):

Below code should Help

```
        const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
        sex: "",
        });

        <div className="flex justify-around">
          <div className="flex items-center mb-4 justify-left">
            <input
              id="country-option-2"
              type="radio"
              name="sex"
              value="male"
              onClick={(e) =>
                setUserData({ ...userData, sex: e.target.value })
              }
              className="w-4 h-4 border-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:focus:bg-blue-600 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600"
            />
            <label
              for="country-option-2"
              className="block ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
            >
              Male
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center mb-4 justify-left">
            <input
              id="country-option-2"
              type="radio"
              name="sex"
              value="female"
              onClick={(e) =>
                setUserData({ ...userData, sex: e.target.value })
              }
              className="w-4 h-4 border-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:focus:bg-blue-600 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600"
            />
            <label
              for="country-option-2"
              className="block ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
            >
              Female
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).